# Ring of invariants of affine ring over field of any characteristic is also affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need to prove that the ring of invariants $T^G$ of an affine ring $T$  over a field of any characteristic is also affine, in other words, to prove it is finitely generated. This is an exercise Ex 13.3 in GTM150. The hint is that use the remark:

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a domain $T$, and let $R$ be the ring of invariants, $R = T^G$. Show that every element of $T$ satisfies an integral equation over $R$ - in fact, each element $b\in T$ is integral over the subring generated by the elementary symmetric functions in the conjugates $\sigma b$.

However, I can't see how to use this. If the field $k$ have a characteristic coprime to order of $G$, I know the theorem can be proved use Reynolds operator. But it seems that this does not work here, and it is not what the hint want us to do. I want to see how $R$ is integral over $T$ will help us prove this.

Comment: For $ b\in T$ then $\prod_{g\in G} (Y-g(b))$ is a monic polynomial $\in R[Y]$ with $b$ in its roots thus $b$ is integral over $R$. Then write $T = k[b_1,\ldots,b_m]$ and $S = k[\cup \sigma_i(b_j)]$ (the symmetric polynomials), $T$ is integral over $S$ means $T$ is a finitely generated $S$ module, $R$ is between them thus it is a finitely generated $S$-module too, thus $R=  S[a_1,\ldots,a_l]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, since $T$ is an integral domain implies $R$ is an integral domain then $R$ is isomorphic to the coordinate ring  of an affine variety.

Comment: @reuns But I doubt about whether R is between them imply R is also finite S-module. I know finite module over finite module is still finite, but I don't know submodule of finite module is finite. I know that he subring of k[x,y] generated by $\{xy^i:i≥0\}$ is not finitely generated over k. If when it comes to module it becomes true, can you show me the reference?

Comment: I realize it. Thanks a lot. I understand it now. But I think the fact that T is noetherian is necessary here, otherwise even for module it is not true.

Comment: $k[x,y]$ is finitely generated algebra not module. You can think in term of $Frac(S)$ vector space obtaining a free $S$-module $M\subset Frac(R)$ such that $ M \supset R\supset sM$, then $R$ corresponds to a sub $S$-module of $M/sM$ ie. of $(S/(s))^N$ and it is a matter of noetherianess of $S$ to show this is finitely generated.